# gstreamer video at 720p and 25/30 fps

Tags: webcam, embedded-linux, gstreamer

i'm trying to stream over the network a USB webcam. I previously manage to do so at 1280x720 with 10 fps but couldn't get to 25 or 30 fps because the camera wasn't powerful enough.
So i bought a new USB camera (Logitech C920) wich is able to do 720p at 30fps (as the documentation says)

The problem is that it is still not working for 25 or 30fps

Here are the gstreamer commands i'm using:

Sender:

```
gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=1280,height=720,framerate=10/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! vpuenc codec=6 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.20.27 port=5000
```

Receiver:

```
gst-launch udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, payload=(int)96, encoding-name=(string)H264" ! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264 ! xvimagesink
```

So this is working at 10fps. When i try to change to more fps, it fails with the following error:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...                                                  
[INFO]  Product Info: i.MX6Q/D/S                                                
vpuenc versions :)                                                              
    plugin: 3.0.11                                                          
    wrapper: 1.0.46(VPUWRAPPER_ARM_LINUX Build on Sep 29 2014 16:56:55)     
    vpulib: 5.4.23                                                          
    firmware: 3.1.1.46056                                                   
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.                                          
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Could not negotiate format                                                                      
Additional debug info:                                                          
/media/philippe/data/fsl-release-bsp/build-x11/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/gstreamer/0.10.36-r3/gstreamer-0.10.36/libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(2830): gst_base_src_start (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:      
Check your filtered caps, if any                                                
Setting pipeline to NULL ...                                                    
Freeing pipeline ...
```

If i delete the width parameter, i get up to 15fps but not more.
As the error states, it could not negotiate format. So i believe i have to change/add/remove the "video/x-raw-yuv,width=1280,height=720,framerate=10/1" parameter. But what should i change to make it works?

PS: if i plug my USB webcam to my computer, i manage to record 720@25fps with VLC without any problems

EDIT: When i add GST_DEBUG=3 before my gst-launch command, some warning shows up.

here's the [report](http://pastebin.com/w5kMsyip)

EDIT AGAIN: since it seems to be a format problem, i tried every single one of this list:
YVU9 YV12 UYVY Y42B Y41B Y41P NV12 NV21 YUV9 I420

only YUY2 works at 10fps (and does not work at 25/30)

Any pointers would be of great help ;)

Thanks

Comment: did you try to change framerate=10/1 to framerate=25/1?

Comment: Yes, i don't get any errors when i use framerate=10/1. But i do get the errors quoted on the original post when i use framerate=25/1

Comment: by reading the pastebin, I think it's a problem of the v4l2 driver of the webcam: ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Could not negotiate format .

Comment: That's also what i figured out. But how do i solve it? Why does it work with 10 fps. Format isn't changing when i switch for 10 fps to 20 fps, am i right?

Comment: It may be a limitation int USB bus of your board or of the camera driver, but I am not sure. I see you have an iMX6, on a sabre light I was able to get 1080p 30fps by using the parallel input connected to the IPU, not with a USB device. By using the mipi input I was able to get 1080p 15fps, by lowering the resolution on mipi I got higher framerates. And this limitation was not due to the mipi input, but the sensor driver.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question on the imx community board and they answered that this is due to a limitation on the USB reading speed of 21Mbps which is not sufficient since 720p@30fps need 30Mbps when not encoded.

Source
https://community.freescale.com/message/353963#353963